# Finding a simple object in a low-quality image

Tags: c#, image, camera, image-recognition

I want to do this thing in C# (or any other .NET language), not sure how:
I have an image I captured from webcam and I want to find a specific simple object in it (let's say a red circle with a black square in it). The red circle can be a bit different from time to time (because of shadows) and the square might be also a bit brighter sometimes and even rotated a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use Open CV
- Compute SURF feature of the object
- Use SURF Tracker to detect the object in image

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Traffic_Sign_Detection_in_CSharp

You can use the above example.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) Wiki article. You might wanna start from there :)

> The Hough transform is a feature
>   extraction technique used in image
>   analysis, computer vision, and digital
>   image processing. The purpose of
>   the technique is to find imperfect
>   instances of objects within a certain
>   class of shapes by a voting procedure.